# Deterministic calculation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I want to create a multiplayer game with HTML/JavaScript and only send user input between players. I read some articles for C++, saying that I could not expect floating point to get the same results on different binaries/machines. I expect the situation to be no better in JavaScript.

Do I need to use fixed point? Assuming fixed point is the way, can I calculate e.g. (estimated reciprocal) square roots using floating point functions exposed thru JavaScript, and then apply something akin to rounding to get determinism?

Comment: Not necessarily an exact duplicate, but definitely related: [Elegant workaround for JavaScript floating point number problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

Comment: A few considerations: 1) if your users send messages to each other an *not* through your server, you open a security risk as now your user **know** stuff about others and 2) if you're sending your data through HTTP, keep in mind that the second *T* of *HTTP* stands for *Text*, in which case your numbers are converted to text before being sent. In c++, this concern is also valid for integer numbers as well and it has to do with endianness, from what I recall.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript as a language does not support any number formats but 64 bit floating point numbers so you can't use true integers (integers in the range of -2^53 to 2^53 can be accurately represented).

Most likely it would be possible to make floating point numbers "act" deterministic through proper rounding and other techniques, however this will require a *lot* of discipline to make and be very hard to debug. Even big game developers like Blizzard struggle with making a game that functions correctly from solely the player inputs.

The problem with floating point differences between computers aren't *that* big, the problem is they accumulate over time and get worse as play progresses, probably the easiest thing to do would be to send player input every network tick and send the variables (position, orientation, etc) of *part* of the game objects along with it. That way you keep bandwidth minimal while keeping the game visually consistent.